# Not enough space on disk in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, disk-usage

i am using ubuntu 14.04, and I got a message saying "not enough space on disc" (or something like that). The problem is that I;m trying to get into ubuntu and delete some files that I don't need (in order to free some space), but after I write my password in the login screen, nothing happens. Maybe Ubuntu can't open because there is so few space left? So, my question is:
How can I access and delete files from ubuntu partition without being inside ubuntu, but from my Windows 8.1 partition (I have a dual boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

Windows can not mount linux partitions.
You can:

- Create a live CD/USB
- Boot from live CD/USB
- Mount hard disk partition
- Delete the files
- Reboot from hard disk

You can find description on how to create a live USB [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get to the login screen then you should be able to access the TTY command line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+F1</kbd> on your keyboard. From here enter your username and password to login to the TTY terminal.

Now you can access your filesystem using `ls -al` to see the files and folders in your current path and the `cd directoryname` to navigate to a different directory. From here you can issue commands such as `rm filename` to delete a file or `rm -r directoryname` to recursively delete every file and folder in the specified directory.

**Note:** The `rm` commands can be very dangerous as they will outright delete the file/directories you specify and once they are deleted they cannot be recovered so be very careful which files/directories to select for deletion while using these commands.

After you've finished deleting the files you want to remove press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+F7</kbd> to exit the TTY and continue to the login screen.